# Mongoose query for documents that got likes on last 24 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have this **article** schema:

```
   var article  = new mongoose.Schema({

    ....

        likes: [{
                    id: ObjectId,
                    by: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
                    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

         }],

....
}, {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at'}});
```

on which I store the likes that the story gets. As you can see the field ***likes*** stores users who liked the article and the time they liked the story.

Now I want to query all the articles that got likes in the last 24 hours. How is that possible to do in Mongoose?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) to get last like date and then use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to check if that date is greater that 24 hours ago:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            lastDate: { $max: "$likes.created_at" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            lastDate: {
                $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Does this fetch only one entry a time ?

Comment: @AlvinZachariah no, it should return all the articles having at least one like added less than 24 hours ago (all likes and other article fields will be returned)